# jquery target specific carousel slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

Hi i am trying to fire some code when the LAST slide is dislayed in the carousel slider sequence using jquery... So far  all javascript/jquery i tried such as hasClass() works, but instantly and not when it's the last slide in it's cycle... thank you for your help

```
$('#carousel1').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    if ( $( "div.item" ).hasClass( "active" )) {
        console.log("SMELLO SMOLRLD");
    }
});
```

```
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner z-depth-2" role="listbox">

            <!-- First slide -->
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="view overlay hm-blue-slight">
                    <a><img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/slides/slide%20(7).jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="slide1">
                        <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs">
                        <div class="animated fadeInDown">
                            <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.item -->

            <!-- Second slide -->
            <div class="item">
                <div class="view overlay hm-blue-slight">
                    <a><img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/slides/slide%20(23).jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="slide2">
                        <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs">
                        <div class="animated fadeInDown">
                            <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.item -->

            <!-- Third slide -->
            <div class="item">
                <div class="view overlay hm-blue-slight">
                    <a><img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/slides/slide%20(2).jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="slide3">
                        <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs">
                        <div class="animated fadeInDown">
                            <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.item -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.carousel-inner -->

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control new-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="fa fa fa-angle-left waves-effect waves-light"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control new-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="fa fa fa-angle-right waves-effect waves-light"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include the code. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: do you see the HTML? i dont have any javascript added bc everything i tried was basic and didnt work

Comment: I see the HTML. But that's just mark-up for a carousel. That doesn't really tell us anything. Show us the JS that you tried and didn't work, and we can start from there. :)

Comment: Okay i just edited it in above thanks

Comment: You've probably got this by now. You can target the last slide div with `$( ".item" ).last().hasClass(...` from https://api.jquery.com/last/